# Go to page option.. find page

Tags: android

I made an app which has 100 pages and change through swipe, but I want to add "Go to page" option so I can go to the specific page easily.

```
public class ViewPagerExampleActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_viewpager_example);
        ExtendedViewPager mViewPager = (ExtendedViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);

        mViewPager.setAdapter(new TouchImageAdapter());
    }

    static class TouchImageAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

        private static int[] images = { R.drawable.page3, R.drawable.page4,
            R.drawable.page5, R.drawable.page6, R.drawable.page7,
            R.drawable.page8, R.drawable.page9, R.drawable.page10, R.drawable.page11,
            R.drawable.page12, R.drawable.page13, R.drawable.page14,
            R.drawable.page15, R.drawable.page16, R.drawable.page17,
            R.drawable.page18, R.drawable.page19, R.drawable.page20, R.drawable.page21,
            R.drawable.page22, R.drawable.page23, R.drawable.page24,
            R.drawable.page25, R.drawable.page26, R.drawable.page27,
            R.drawable.page28, R.drawable.page29, R.drawable.page30,
            R.drawable.page31, R.drawable.page32, R.drawable.page33, R.drawable.page34,
            R.drawable.page35, R.drawable.page36, R.drawable.page37,
            R.drawable.page38, R.drawable.page39, R.drawable.page40, R.drawable.page41,
            R.drawable.page42, R.drawable.page43, R.drawable.page44,
            R.drawable.page45, R.drawable.page46, R.drawable.page47,
            R.drawable.page48, R.drawable.page49, R.drawable.page50, R.drawable.page51,
            R.drawable.page52, R.drawable.page53, R.drawable.page54,
            R.drawable.page55, R.drawable.page56, R.drawable.page57,
            R.drawable.page58, R.drawable.page59, R.drawable.page60, R.drawable.page61,
            R.drawable.page62, R.drawable.page63, R.drawable.page64,
            R.drawable.page65, R.drawable.page66, R.drawable.page67,
            R.drawable.page68, R.drawable.page69, R.drawable.page70, R.drawable.page71,
            R.drawable.page72, R.drawable.page73, R.drawable.page74 };

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return images.length;
        }

        @Override
        public View instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
            TouchImageView img = new TouchImageView(container.getContext());
            img.setImageResource(images[position]);
            container.addView(img, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
            return img;
        }

        @Override
        public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
            container.removeView((View) object);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
            return view == object;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

    }

    long lastPress;
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onBackPressed();
        if (interstitial.isLoaded())
            interstitial.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: so what's your question......

Comment: how to add search page option to it so i can go to page directly..

Answer (score 0):

To switch the `ViewPager` to a specific page, you just need to call [`setCurrentItem()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setCurrentItem%28int%29).

Comment: Can You send Me some Example If Its Possible...& Thanks For Your Answer